# what is the differenet between two array functions in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Please see the below array

`$array1 = array("b" => "boy", "c" => "cat", "A"=>"boy");`

Now I am going to use the `array_flip` function here

```
array_flip($array1); // I am going to print it in next line
print_r($array1) // but array flip has not been worked
```

See the next function called `ksort`

```
ksort($array1) // called first then print in next line
print_r($array1);
```

Now it is going to print the value in ascending order key wise

So my question is that what is the difference between `array_flip` and `ksort` function

Because I called both of the function before print and one works and other does not.

Please help me out guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: rtfm. array flip swaps the keys in the array with the values, ksort sorts the array by the keys.

Comment: you also need to re-assign the array flip value ... `$array = array_flip($array);` otherwise it does nothing

Comment: See the manual: [`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip), [`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort). It explains the difference between modifying the parameter or returning the result.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the way these functions are described in the PHP docs

```
array array_flip ( array $array )
  ^
  |
 Means that function returns an array
```

and

```
bool ksort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
  ^                ^
  |                |
  |               Means argument is passed by reference, and the original argument will be changed
Means function returns a boolean
```

Comment: omg i missed a big thing, thanks so much for making me aware about that next time i will keep it in mind.pass by reference is really a big thing.
one more thing need to ask you
can i presume anytime when i find any function which return boolean would accept the first arguement variable as pass by reference.
or every time need to see the doc about the specific function

Comment: No you can't make that assumption, because a lot of functions return a Boolean but don't use pass by reference (e.g. is_numeric())... it's always worthwhile checking with the docs, or using an IDE that tells you this; though in time you'll come to know the details of the functions that you use most regularly

Comment: understood
thanks so much for your precious time.

Answer (score 6):

`array_flip` is a function that accepts an array as argument and **returns** an altered array.
`ksort` is a function that accepts its array argument **by reference** and alters the array in place.

`array_flip` produces a new value without altering its input value, `ksort` alters its input value directly. In your case, since you're not doing anything with the return value of `array_flip`, it just gets discarded and you're not seeing the effect.